# Android: Provider Test Case 2 and getFilesDir()

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Part of my application involves saving a png file to my local files directory, and then shared via a content provider.

I write the file via `getContext().openFileOutput`

However, in my content provider, `ParcelFileDescriptor` will only open actual File objects. So trying to do this via a mocked out content provider using `ProviderTestCase2`, the following code doesn't work:

```
return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), filename), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
```

This is because `context.getFilesDir()` points to `/dev/null` in the mock context given to the provider via the `ProviderTestCase2` code. The code above results in an exception because `/dev/null` doesn't count as a directory. Is this as intended?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a joke... The docs say:

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

But the IsolatedContext source is this:

```
@Override
public File getFilesDir() {
    return new File("/dev/null");
}
```

So we have better ignoring that method and try with

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
```

in out tests.