# Android InstrumentationTestCase getFilesDir() returns null

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am using `InstrumentationTestCase` to unit test a component of my application.

The component persists data to the internal storage and uses `Context::fileList();` to retrieve the persisted files.

I experience the following problem: Using this method in the app (on the device) works perfectly fine. But when I try to (Android-)Unit-Test (also on the Device) with use of `InstrumentationTestCase` I get a `NullPointerException` inside the `fileList()` method. I digged into the android source and found out that `getFilesDir()` [(see source here)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.getFilesDir%28%29) returns null and causes this error.

The code to reproduce is the following:

```
public class MyTestCase extends InstrumentationTestCase
{   
    public void testExample() throws Exception
    {
        assertNotNull(getInstrumentation().getContext().getFilesDir()); // Fails
    }
}
```

My questions are: Is this behaviour intended? What can I do to circumvent this issue? Am I using `InstrumentationTestCase` right or should I use something different?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796529/android-provider-test-case-2-and-getfilesdir) but I'm not sure if this covers the same problem I have.

Comment: Did you try to use getTargetContext() instead of getContext()

Comment: Well, yes. `getTargetContext()` works as expected, but I want the tests to run (more or less) independently of the App. That's the reason I chose `InstrumentationTestCase`.

Comment: As the name stated, InstrumentationTestCase is an instrumentation test, by using the second test app to instrument the main app for testing Android component, for instance activity is properly renderred or user interaction is correctly handled. It doesn't make much sense to run the test app independently from the main app.

Comment: @yorkw Yeah, I already was in doubt if this is correct what I am doing. So in case I need a prepared dataset, would you suggest the following? Perform a 'backup' of current data, write the prepared dataset, perform test, delete test data, restore backup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you are right with keeping your test data separate from tested application.

You can fix problem with `Null` by creating `files` directory for `Instrumentation` app by executing the following commands

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/<package_id_of_instrumentation_app>
mkdir files
```

You can do above only on emulator or rooted device.

Then test from your question will not fail. I did it and also uploaded file named `tst.txt` to `files` dir, all below tests were successful:

```
assertNotNull(getInstrumentation().getContext().getFilesDir());
assertNotNull(getInstrumentation().getContext().openFileInput("tst.txt"));
assertNotNull(getInstrumentation().getContext().openFileOutput("out.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

But I think more convenient way to provide data to test project is to use `assets` of test project where you can simply save some files and open them:

```
assertNotNull(getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("asset.txt"));
```

or if you want to save some results of tests to the file you can use `ExternalStorage`:

```
File extStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
assertNotNull(extStorage);
```

Comment: +1 nice one. The shell fix allowed me for unit testing data persistance based on Realm.io.

Comment: Why is files dir not present in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

[@Blackbelt mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317793/android-instrumentationtestcase-getfilesdir-returns-null#comment19895493_14317793) to use [`getTargetContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#getTargetContext()) instead of [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#getContext()). I missed the comment, and after a few hours, of trying to figure out [how to Realm.init() from an Android instrumented tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59676354/2898715), I find out that I need the Context from [`getTargetContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#getTargetContext())...(along the way, i tried to `context.filesDir.mkdirs()`)

```
package com.github.ericytsang

import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import org.junit.Test

class InstrumentedTest {

    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

    @Test
    fun can_mkdirs() {
        assert(context.filesDir.mkdirs())
    }
}
```